# vertical align img

Tags: css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a div called `images_box` which has a width of `277px`. Within that div I have 9 images in it, just stored as `<a>` tags. I've got the images to float left and line up quite nicely within my div, but I would like the images to align vertically, as some are portrait and others are landscape. I know I can do this if I enclose each image in a div, but the plugin I use to launch the gallery won't recognise which image is being fired, so i need to enclose them as just within the `<a>` tags.

This is the code I have, if someone can help me just align the images horizontally and vertically. I don't want the images to be skewed.

```
#images_box a {
    float: left;
    padding: 9px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

my data

```
<div id="images_box">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7069/7060779347_fbee5aae15_b.jpg" title="morning after[explored] (mariosworld343)">
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7069/7060779347_fbee5aae15_m.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7234/7047458501_46a2203733_b.jpg" title="Self confined... (TVidhya)">
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7234/7047458501_46a2203733_m.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7053/6918451990_20fa76f338_b.jpg" title="kleiner schrittmacher (KatjaGiersig)">
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7053/6918451990_20fa76f338_m.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7121/7059981833_abe404f4a0_b.jpg" title="(caro diario.)">
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7121/7059981833_abe404f4a0_m.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for vertical centering around a center line regardless of image height, or vertical alignment to top?

Comment: Try adding a `line-height: 70px`. Also clean up your question a bit. Your html says `images` and your css `imagesbox`. Also the images in your html are much larger than 70px.

Comment: Hi Tom, yes thats exactly what I am trying to do. Gerben, thanks, updated original post - added your suggestion, but my images are still top aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i figured out what you want. `float: left` to get the images side by side is not necessary.

```
#images_box {
    background: #eee;
    overflow: hidden; /* this div will get the height of the tallest element inside it */
    white-space: nowrap; /* prevent line-breaks */
}


#images_box a {
    padding:9px;
    display: inline-block; /* required to apply vertical-align as expected */
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

**Works in**:

- Internet Explorer 6+
- and modern browsers

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/vjDVp/1/

Comment: Thanks top-trois, your solution is bang on, solves the issue I had. I'm surprised you don't need the float:left - thought that was the only way to get pictures flowing in my div properly, but obviously not. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it seems like you're looking for:

```
#images a {
    padding: 9px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Where you can tweak the `vertical-align` to `top` or `middle`, as needed. There's no need for floats. The dimensions you've described in your original question are off, so apologies if I've misunderstood.

Note also that `display: table-cell` is not IE6/7-friendly, if that matters.

Comment: Hi Tom, that does exactly what I want, although the images are not contained in my div. So I add a float:left, and the images get aligned at the top and not the centre.

Answer (score 0):

Set the css to the images, not the `a` tags. Give them a classname (to make sure your other images are not affected) and apply the code you provided in your question to that (`img.myclass`). Or, at least the `vertical-align`.

Also, what are the sizes of the images? Do they all have the same width, same height or a certain size depending on whether it's a landscape or portrait image?

Oh and I don't know why, but `text-align` seems to work on img tags too sometimes.